# Import Excel spreadsheet into phpMyAdmin

Tags: excel, csv, phpmyadmin, xlsx

I have been trying to import an excel (xlsx) file into phpMyAdmin.

I have tried as both excel and **csv** file. I have tried csv and csv using load data.

I have replaced the default field termination value from `;` to `,`.

Most times I was getting an variety of error messages, so I deleted my field names column and then was able to import a single row of data only.

The data was off by a column, and I guess that has something to do with the structure of my table, which has a field for `ID#` as a primary auto-incrementing field which is not in my csv file.

I tried adding a column for that before importing with no success. I would have thought that I could import right from the **xlsx** file as that is one of the choices in phpMyAdmin but everything I read or watch online converts to **csv**.

I could use some help here.

Comment: Could you post the error messages? They would help to solve the problem.

Comment: for xlsx - You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (application/zip). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.

Comment: for csv - Invalid field count in CSV input on line 1.

Comment: and after you removed the first line, there were no error messages just the ID problem?

Comment: No, I get the error messages unless I use csv with load data - then I get the problem with the data being off by a column.

Comment: I am now totally baffled. I finally got the data to import using excel xls (instead of xlsx) format. Now my database looks correct. I have another test database I set up using about 7 records. The test database functions properly with no issues. When I change the code in my php file to use the live database rather than the test database I get error messages which I just can't figure out.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/troop97/public_html/oabtest.php on line 131

results found for P

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/troop97/public_html/oabtest.php on line 136

Comment: Figured last part out - had some field names in php file that didn't match up - fixed them and now it looks to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that I solved it by changing the 'fields enclosed by' option from `"` (double quote) to `'` (single quote) and doing the same to the first line of the file which contains the field names. Worked like a charm. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is hopelessly late, but I'm replying in the hope that this might help a future viewer.

The reason that the CSV data is off by one is the very fact that you don't have the ID# field in it! The way to get around this is to import the file into a temporary table, then run

```
INSERT INTO `table`
SELECT NULL, <field1>, <field2>...
FROM `temp table`;
```

Adding `NULL` to the list of fields means that MySQL will autogenerate the ID# field (assuming you've set it to `AUTO_INCREMENT`).